# Is there any user level privilege in Informix?

Tags: informix, privileges

As I read, there are certain access [privileges](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.ddi.doc/ids_ddi_105.htm) given to a user or role in Informix. If I give any of the database level privilege, it will have access to all users/ schemas under that database. 
My doubt was that can I restrict this privilege to specific users/ schemas in that database? Do we have any user/schema level privilege in Informix?

Comment: I have a suspicion that we have a nomenclature problem.  I recognize the words you're using, but you aren't applying them in a way that makes sense to me in the context of Informix.  In particular, "schemas" are essentially non-existent in Informix databases.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler do you mean tables directly reside under database in informix? Just for my knowledge, could you please explain what is the use of [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0483.htm) in that case. Why am I able to create schema with **CREATE SCHEMA authorization test;** Also, I am able to create objects within it

Comment: I've used the CREATE SCHEMA statement maybe half a dozen times in the last 30+ years of working with Informix, and each time solely for the purpose of checking that it works.  After the CREATE SCHEMA statement completes, there is no way to distinguish the tables, indexes, permissions created from those created without the use of CREATE SCHEMA but with the appropriate AUTHORIZATION (user).  There is no record in the database that the tables and indexes were created as part of a CREATE SCHEMA statement.  There is no way to drop the schema that was created in a single statement.

Comment: That's what I mean by "essentially non-existent".  There is no record in the database that a 'schema' (CREATE SCHEMA statement) was used to create things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you grant a user CONNECT privilege to a database, then they can access tables within that database for which they have been granted access (which is typically, but not necessarily, all tables in the database).  You can also revoke PUBLIC privileges on a table, and then grant access only to named users or roles, and then only those users who have been granted access can access it.  Here, "access" means "if they try to SELECT, they need to have been granted SELECT access; if they try to INSERT, they need to have been granted INSERT access; etc.".

By default, when you create a table in an ordinary database, then all users are given select, insert, update, delete privileges on the table.  This is done via the equivalent of `GRANT ALL ON the_table TO PUBLIC`.  Note that every user has the permissions granted to PUBLIC, and possibly some extra privileges.  Therefore, to ensure only selected users or roles have access, it is necessary to use `REVOKE ALL ON the_table FROM PUBLIC`.  There is an environment variable `NODEFDAC=1` and a `$ONCONFIG` file setting with the same name that suppresses the default 'discretionary access controls' (DAC) granted to PUBLIC.  Note that in a MODE ANSI database, no permissions are granted to anyone else by default.

The constraints on users granted RESOURCE privilege in a database are similar users granted CONNECT privilege — the difference is that RESOURCE users can create their own tables, whereas CONNECT users cannot.

If a user is granted DBA privilege, they can access any tables in the database.  Be cautious about granting DBA privilege, therefore.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler for your response. Can you please elaborate on mode ANSI database you mentioned above. How do we give privilege in this case?

Comment: If you run `CREATE DATABASE mode_ansi WITH LOG MODE ANSI;`, you create a mode ANSI database. These are different from non-ANSI databases in Informix.  One difference is that almost any operation (except COMMIT or ROLLBACK) starts a transaction.  Another is that if you don't own the tables you are referencing, you need to specify the owner(s) of those tables — you might regard 'owner' as equivalent to 'schema' and we could have a fraught discussion about it.  Another difference is that by default, when a table is created, PUBLIC is not given access. You have to GRANT permission.